# How to use current time in seed number of ELM random

Tags: random, elm

Random seed in Elm programming. If I use fixed seed I will get same random number. How can I use current time in seed number? I am using Elm 0.19.

```
Random.initialSeed <currentTime>
```

So - how to get current time or start time to ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Time.now`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/time/latest/Time#now) to get a `Task` which can produce the current time, or [`Time.every`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/time/latest/Time#every) to subscribe to time updates.

However, if you're just trying to avoid having your random values be predictable, you will want to use [`Random.generate`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/random/latest/Random#generate), which produces a `Cmd` which will trigger a message with the generated value.  This prevents you from having to deal with `Seed` values.